# How to correctly us OmniPay PayPal Rest

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, omnipay

I am trying to use OmniPay PayPal (REST), but I a facing several problems so I would like to ask:

1. Is it still maintained ? https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-paypal
2. In PHP file docs there is link @link https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#create-a-payment which does not exists. Is it some kind of old version of PayPal API?
3. Is there any better documentation? I only found lots of website using the same tutorial.
4. For example there is written to use 'returnUrl' property directly in purchase object, but in PayPal documentation it should be under 'application_context' property. So where is the truth?

Thank you

I tried to google tutorials, but there is always only one same small example.

Answer (score 0):

See the current [standard integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/), which uses the v2/checkout/orders API to create and capture an order from a backend. The sample index.js file there is in node, but those two routes to create and capture an order can of course be implemented in any backend of choice, including PHP.

No redirects should be used for approval, and those backend routes should output JSON only (never any HTML nor debug text) and be called by a JS frontend, see the examples there for details.